# How to make an on-the-fly refresh on Google Maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps, service, google-maps-markers

I'm using Services do calculating the LatLng from some addresses stored in a database. When I have a lot of addresses, it's slower to calculate and when I open Google Maps, it doesn't have all the Markers displayed on the screen, because the Service is still calculating in background. Is there a way to Markers appear automatically with the Maps still opened?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably geocode the data when it is entered into the database instead of at the time it is displayed.  As you have seen, geocoding is slow, and it would be better to cache the geocoded results.  Or at least save the geocoded result the first time you encounter an address.

Note: Google has restrictions on what you can use its geocoding service for.  If you used Google's geocoding, then you are only allowed to use that lat/lng with the Google Maps API.

There do exist free/open source geocoders.  In my opinion/experience, Google's geocoders is better than the open source ones.  (But it has restrictions.)

Comment: That's exactly what I was doing, that's why I changed this calculate to a service. This service is running in background to calculate, so when I open Google Maps, this ask all the lat/lng to the database, but the service is still running in background so some lat/lng was already calculated, but some others not, then some Markers is already placed. So is there a way to the markers is showing up automatically with the service running in background?

Comment: And yes, I'm using Google Maps API v2. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ah, I infer that the lat/lngs change more rapidly than I presumed. You might be able to set up a Javascript callback.  I'm not sure if it would be practical to get a callback for every geocode, but you ought to be able to issue a callback when all the geocodes are done.  http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/